# Route nesting in react-router-dom V6 not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to react-router-dom V6 and am having some trouble getting nested routes to work as I expect.

I have an AppRoutes file:

```
export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/quotes/*"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <Quotes />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      >
        <Route path="pending/:id/*" element={<PendingQuote />} />
      </Route>

      // ... other routes

      <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

I then have a component that attempts to render some nested routes:

```
export default function PendingQuote() {
  const { id } = useParams()
  console.log("ID from params:", id)
  return (
    <>
      <TopBanner />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="general-information" element={<GeneralInformation />} />
        <Route path="sections" element={<Sections />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

When I try to access one of the nested routed via `http://localhost:5173/quotes/pending/123/sections` I can see the `<TopBanner />` component as expected but no nested routes.

By stubbing my toe and more by chance I found that if I visited `http://localhost:5173/quotes/sections` I can see the nested routes.

To ensure that the `<Quotes />` component wasn't the problem I then stripped that back to:

```
import PendingQuote from "./pending/PendingQuote"

export default function Quotes() {
  return (
    <>
      <PendingQuote />
    </>
  )
}
```

As a last shot at diagnosing the problem I made another nested route but only one level deep like so:

```
 <Route
    path="/deals/*"
    element={
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <Deals />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    }
  >
    <Route path="test" element={<GeneralInformation />} />
  </Route>
```

I then visited `http://localhost:5173/deals/test` but only got the `<Deals />` component to render.

I am using [Redux Toolkit Vite Starter Template](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started#installation)

Any help to resolve would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you [edit] to share the `Quotes` component code you are really trying to use, the one from the first snippet where it's the parent layout route component? See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for responding, It really is only that pretty much right now as I am just trying to scaffold the routes out.

Comment: Well, based on what I can see of your code, you've some confusion on the difference between ***nested*** routes, e.g. `Route` component nested in `Route` component, and ***descendent*** routes, e.g. a routed component rendering a `Routes` and sub-routes. The former only requires the routed component to render an `Outlet` for the nested routes, the latter requires the trailing `"*"` splat so descendent paths can also be matched. We can't see all that is between `path="/quotes/*"` and `Quotes` and the more deeply nested routed components you want rendered.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much for letting me get out on time on a Friday!